# React Native Boilerplate template

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm a ReactJS developer, and I'm learning **React Native** for an upcoming project. 
With ReactJS, there is a great **boilerplate** which is widely used by ReactJS developer: https://www.reactboilerplate.com/ (There are also many other great boilerplate).

However, after researching for a day, I haven't figured something similar to **React Native**. Please, can someone suggest to me a **boilerplate** for **React Native**?. Is there a **standard project structure** out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually there is not much difference from ReactJs. It really depends on navigation library you are choosing. The best options are:

1. [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/) (JS based navigation library)
2. [React Native Navigation](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/) (Native navigation library)

I suggest seeing example projects of both libraries.

Comment: Does it mean I can combine ReactJS boilerplate + a navigation library for React Native?

Comment: Yes, but remember that render element are different. You can use a project like [React Native Web](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web) to get a result in web as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app

Also read documentation about React Navigation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the react native Ignite CLI [Github](https://github.com/infinitered/ignite) which seems to be very similar, it's probably one of the most advanced Boilerplates for React Native and can be difficult to understand, thus when starting with React Native I would advise you to use none at all or just use your React structure

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the Handidev boilerplate since it only consists of the minimum library that every react-native project uses. And it has been used in many projects. This boilerplate consists of :

```
latest react-native version
react-navigation and its dependencies
redux-toolkit ( state management)
react-native vector icons ( for icons)
```

You can check it out here:

- javascript version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@handidev/react-native-boilerplate

`npx react-native init MyApp --template @handidev/react-native-boilerplate`

- TypeScript version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@handidev/react-native-typescript-boilerplate

`npx react-native init MyAppName --template @handidev/react-native-typescript-boilerplate`